# What is the best way to have user enter their Age in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, webforms

Instead of having a user enter their age (e.g. "27") inside a textbox or use a drop down list to select a number ranging for 15 to 99, is there a quicker way to get user to select their age?

I came across a sample code the other day which has an **up/down arrow** to let the user move the number up/down to the right age. I can't seem to find the page now.

Is that the best way? If so, would be helpful if you know where the sample code is!

Thanks.

Comment: just a side note: isn't it better to let users insert date of birth instead that plain age?

Comment: As Jack says, I think the best way to get age is not to get it at all, but derive it from birthdate, if the user is willing to share. Otherwise, 'age' must be updated yearly, manually (and therefore, can never be considered to be accurate)

Comment: Also as a side note; Is it just me who finds that by FAR the easiest way to enter my age is by typing it in? It's easier to hit two digits than to scroll/click/whatever up/down any more than *two* digits.

Comment: Good point about getting DOB instead of that SOB Age field. Will dig around for a good way to collect DOB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds all very over thought and possibly over engineered.

```
<input type="text" name="age" maxlength="3">
```

That should be sufficient.

If you need anything else, a key listener to ensure that the provided value is a positive, non-zero integer should be the extent of your UI enhancements.

Edit: To address the comments, of course server side validation are *always* required, regardless of client side restrictions and validation.  I left them out since it wasn't required in the scope of the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I do want to think outside the box a lot. Must.. get.. DOB now.

Comment: In the end I decided to just get the age.. and then store data as BirthYear immediately. I think that is the best way so people don't get annoyed with entering their DOB.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner components are quite slow compared to allowing raw text input data.  I personally can't stand when websites make me select my age via drop down menus.  Even worse is when they separate it to month / day / year.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative could be asking for the birth date and then, calculate the age. You have lots of javascript samples [here](http://www.google.es/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=calculate+age+from+birth#sclient=psy&hl=es&q=age+calculator&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=792c20d92117c5a6)

In other case, the best alternative is the second one, maybe user a [spinner](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner#Example) jQuery contol.